# Angular JSON request goes through, response not being saved to variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a user's profile page on a [angular-rails tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#beginning-rails) I went through. I have in the following order:

> /javascripts/users/_users.html

```
    User's Profile Page
    {{user.email}}
```

> /javascripts/users/users.js

```
    angular.module('flapperNews').factory('users', ['$http', function($http){
      var o = {
        users: []
      };

      o.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/users/' + id + '.json').then(function(res){      
            return res.data;
        });
      };

      return o;
    }])
```

> /javascripts/users/usersCtrl.js

```
    angular.module('flapperNews')
    .controller('UsersCtrl', [
      '$scope',
      'users',
      'user',
      function($scope, users, user){
        $scope.user = user;


    }])
```

My `app.js` state reflects this change as such:

```
  .state('users', {
    url: '/users/{id}',
    templateUrl: 'users/_users.html',
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    resolve: {
      post: ['$stateParams', 'users', function($stateParams, users) {
        return users.get($stateParams.id);
      }]
    }
  })
```

And the user's controller looks like this:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

        def show
        respond_with User.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

And routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users
  devise_for :installs
  root to: 'application#angular'

  resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :create] do
      member do
        put '/upvote' => 'comments#upvote'
      end
    end

    member do
      put '/upvote' => 'posts#upvote'
    end
  end

  resources :users

end
```

When logging in with `user id = 2` and trying to hit the profile page, it seems to go through:

```
    Started GET "/users/2.json" for ::1 at 2015-10-27 23:07:23 -0400
    Processing by UsersController#show as JSON
      Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
      User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
    Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

But on the actual page I'm left with a hardcoded:

```
User's Profile Page
{{user.email}}
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple, any ideas what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement executes before the data is actually populated by from the `$http` call. You need to use `$q`.

In service:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('job.json')
    .success(function(response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
return deferred.promise;
```

In controller:

```
var p = <serviceCall>
p.then(function(s){
   $scope.ans=s;
})
```

`$q` is used for getting synchronous response. For more details read the **Angular Docs**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I'm going to try this when I get home, one problem however: all the other features in the tutorial are setup exactly like this (e.g. posts), and they work. So why do they work, and this doesn't ? are those "asynchronous" responses ?